# GSheets, turn script on and off with a key word

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a very simple script with two questions, I've searched for answers and nothing i've tried works. I hope someone can add to the script i have added below.

1. When I make an edit, it sorts as i'd like. I would like only "sheet1" to react to the script. At this time an edit on sheet2 will sort sheet2 ect...
2. I would like to turn the script on and off with a key word in cell "A9" on sheet1 Saying "sort on", when i erase this "sort on" in "A9" I'd like it to turn the script off.

Thank you for taking the time to look. I feel silly even having to ask.

```
    function onEdit(event){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    var tableRange = "A2:Z999";

    if(editedCell);
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : 2 } );
    range.sort( { column : 4 } );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to Stack!

You're using `getActiveSpreadsheet()` which is creating your var `sheet` for the current active sheet being used.

E.g. you're on sheet 'Foo' that is the active sheet. You then switch to sheet 'Bar' and now that is the active sheet. You want to specify which sheet the function needs to fire on

You want to use the function `.getSheetByName("NAME_HERE")`

Try changing your code to `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("NAME_HERE")`

And here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)